# Install pandera[pyspark]-compatible version of pydantic on Databricks cluster

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, pydantic, pandera

I have an issue with installing pandera[pyspark] and pydantic on my Databricks cluster.

### Background

I have a data pipeline in Databricks notebooks. It is completely written in PySpark, so for my data validation I want to use [the pyspark version of pandera](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyspark_sql.html).

### Issue

When I include the latest PyPi versions of pandera[pyspark] (0.17.2) and pydantic (2.4.2) in the configuration of my cluster, they install. However, when I want to import something from pandera.pyspark (for example, `from pandera.pyspark import DataFrameSchema`) I get the following error: `AttributeError: Module 'pydantic' has no attribute '__version__'`. I have looked at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69826648/attributeerror-module-pydantic-has-no-attribute-version-when-running-py), but according to [the github issue linked in the answer](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/2572) it seems to be [fixed](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/pull/2573) in the newer versions of pydantic.

Strangely, if I don't install the libraries on the cluster and instead run the following lines in my data validation notebook:

```
!pip install --upgrade pydantic
!pip install pandera[pyspark]
```

Then I can import `DataFrameSchema` without any issues and run the validation script. Still, these lines result in the latest PyPi versions for pandera and pydantic as well.

### Question

How can it be that the same combination of pandera and pydantic versions give issues in the cluster configuration, but not when installed in a notebook cell? Might there be an alternative way of installing these packages correctly to my cluster?